# Submit a post xml request to webservice hosted on weblogic and get a response xml from client request

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic12c

I am trying to send post requests to a webservice that is in weblogic.
I am using soapui to make the requests, this tool structures me the object that I have to send to XML format, but when I send the request it gives me the error: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond.

Any ideas ?
The webservice I did, it is not that I am consulting any external.

JDNI connection:

```
if ( conn == null ){

        Context ctx = null;

        try{

            ctx = new InitialContext();

            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc_oracle_ws");

            conn = ds.getConnection();

        }catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

Code webservice method

```
@WebService(serviceName = "ConsultarRecibosPendientes", targetNamespace = "http://websercice.fi.co/")
public class ConsultarRecibosPendientes extends Base {

        @WebMethod(operationName = "ConsultarRecibosPendientes")
        @WebResult(name = "ConsultarRecibosPendientesResult")
        public ConsultarRecibosPendientesRes ConsultarRecibosPendientes(@WebParam(
                name = "ConsultarRecibosPendientesReq") ConsultarRecibosPendientesReq objeto) {

            ConsultarRecibosPendientesRes recibosRes = new ConsultarRecibosPendientesRes();

            cliente_servicio = ConsultarInformacionClienteServicio( objeto.nCodBanco,
                                                                        objeto.nCodAgencia,
                                                                        objeto.nCodInstitucion,
                                                                        objeto.nCodConvenio,
                                                                        objeto.nTipoBusqueda,
                                                                        objeto.nTipoLlaveAcceso,
                                                                        objeto.strLlaveAcceso);

            recibosRes.nCodRespuesta = cliente_servicio.codigoRespuesta;
            recibosRes.nTipoIdentificacion = cliente_servicio.tipoIdentificacion;
            recibosRes.strIdentificacion = cliente_servicio.identificacionCliente.replace("-", "").trim();
            recibosRes.strNombreCliente = cliente_servicio.nombreCliente;
            recibosRes.nFechaTransaccion = cliente_servicio.fechaTransaccion;
            recibosRes.nCantServicios = cliente_servicio.cantServicios;

            return recibosRes;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you confirm the url definitely responds to a http request, e.g. via browser?

Comment: The URL http: // IP: 7001 / connectivity / ConsultRecibosPendientes? WSDL, answers me without problems.
I really do not know what I'm doing wrong :( the deploy to GlassFish does not give me problems, it's when I deal with the WebLogic.

Comment: You'll probably have to consult whoever looks after the WebLogic instance I think - sorry, but this is probably very dependent on the detailed configuration of WebLogic and/or your network.

Comment: I already know what the error is, however I am seeing how to solve it. The problem now is that the WebService in the WebLogic is not receiving me the object that I send by parameter, it receives it as null.

Comment: The previous problem was the format of the XML that I was sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection to the database is fine, you just have to create a "data source" on the WebLogic server with the specifications we need, in my case a thin oracle instance connection.

Then, as I defined certain properties of the XML in my code, the XML that generates automatic SOAP UI was not serving me, I had to create the XML following my specifications, so I could get communication with the WebService.

The XML that served me was the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <web:ConsultarRecibosPendientes xmlns:web="http://websercice.fi.co/">
            <oReq>
                <nCodBanco>150</nCodBanco>
                <nCodAgencia>1</nCodAgencia>
                <nCodInstitucion>1</nCodInstitucion>
                <nCodConvenio>1</nCodConvenio>
                <nTipoBusqueda>1</nTipoBusqueda>
                <nTipoLlaveAcceso>1</nTipoLlaveAcceso>
                <strLlaveAcceso>llave de acceso</strLlaveAcceso>
            </oReq>
        </web:ConsultarRecibosPendientes>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Apart from this I changed the name to the parameter by "oReq", like this:

```
public ConsultarRecibosPendientesRes ConsultarRecibosPendientes(
                              @WebParam(name = "oReq", targetNamespace = "")
                              ConsultarRecibosPendientesReq oReq) {...}
```